# Using Vue.js with Nunjucks

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nunjucks

My company has a build system for static sites using nunjucks for the html rendering. I would like to add Vue.js to do some prototyping. I don't want to use nunjucks in my Vue templates. I have an index.njk page that I would like to add Vue to. When I run the command that serves the pages everything builds just fine but I get no output from Vue.

Index.njk

```
{% block content %}
<main class="wrapper">
    <div class="prod-switcher">
        <prod-tabs></prod-tabs>
    </div>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

I then use `.prod-switcher` as the `el` for Vue. The build system is using express for the server with webpack middleware for hot module reloading. So in the server.js file there is this bit.

```
files.forEach(fileName => {
            app.get(`/${fileName.replace('njk', 'html')}`, function(req, res) {
                const data = getDataFile(fileName);
                return res.render(fileName, data);
            });
        });
```

It's just looking for all the `njk` files and rendering them. Nothing actually gets outputted to the file system. When I look at the page in the browser I can see that the `.prod-switcher` element is gone but this is what's in it's place.

```
<main class="wrapper">
    <!--function (a, b, c, d) { return createElement(vm, a, b, c, d, true); }-->
</main>
```

Vue-loader is being used in webpack. Does anyone if it's possible to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out webpack was resolving to a runtime version of Vue. If I add an alias property to point to `vue.esm.js` everything works

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    }
}
```